# is it better to use query builder or eloquent with laravel for avoiding sql injection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-injection

using the query builder in this way, makes my code vulnerable to sql injection?I have this in my controller and i don't know if it's right doing this, or maybe is better to use eloquent.

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
   public function index()
   {
       $genus = \DB::select('SELECT * FROM genus');       
       return view('formulario',['genus'=>$genus]);
   }     
}
```

Comment: The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.Refer to Laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#introduction

Comment: Both are equally good/bad at preventing sql injections. It depends on the developer. As long as you avoid using raw methods or make sure the user's input is escaped when doing so, you don't have to worry.